# Can chiropractor really fix lateral pelvic tilt?

Tags: posture

I have a lateral pelvic tilt (left hip up, right down, upper body turned toward the right side, left shoulder seems down)

I had this issue recently (I'm grown up with symetric pelvis) because (**im not sure**) I've done lot lot of house work (cleaning)

Today I visited a chiropractor and he confirmed that the pelvis is tilted and he made a small manipulation and he said that the pelvis is again in place.

but I'm so skeptic about that ( I still see the asymmetry in my pelvis), I dont think that a small one shot maneuver could fix my tilt. I've tried many exercises but nothing helped

does anyone of you had a pelvic tilt issue and can a chiropractor realy fix it wih a single shot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right to be skeptical about this, because a lateral pelvic tilt can be caused by either something very severe, or something mild.

> I had this issue recently (I'm grown up with symetric pelvis) because (im not sure) I've done lot lot of house work (cleaning)

This suggests that the cause for this lateral pelvic tilt (LPT for now) is not very severe. LPT can be caused by scoliosis, in which case a chiropractor would possibly only be a small part of a much more elaborate solution. And often times, the solution wouldn't even be a complete fix.

Since this is something you've developed recently, it's likely due to postures you've imposed on yourself for long periods of time. It could be the way to sit (pay close attention to this in the future), or indeed extended physical labor with poor posture.

> Today I visited a chiropractor and he confirmed that the pelvis is tilted and he made a small manipulation and he said that the pelvis is again in place.

It's likely he meant temporarily. If, for example, the tilt is caused by a shortening of the hip flexor, **the tilt will arise again and again, until you fix the *source* of the problem**. We can rebuild a house over and over, but if you keep building it in a sand-pit, it will always crumble.

> but I'm so skeptic about that ( I still see the asymmetry in my pelvis), I dont think that a small one shot maneuver could fix my tilt. I've tried many exercises but nothing helped

You should see a physical therapist and find the root of the problem. If, for example, it *is* caused by a shortened hip flexor, you will need an elaborate therapy plan involving some light workouts with focus on stretching. This is not something we can create for you on this site, since we don't know your entire situation.

> does anyone of you had a pelvic tilt issue and can a chiropractor realy fix it wih a single shot

Possibly. If the tilt was caused by a single day of intense work with poor posture, it's likely that the problem isn't very deeply rooted. Easy come, easy go.

But a problem that has manifested itself over a longer period of time, will require a solution to be applied over a longer period of time.

**Bottom line**

He can fix the tilt, but if he didn't fix the *cause* of the tilt, it will just keep tilting.

Comment: the chiropractor said that he set back the pelvis in its place, but I can still my belly uneven (tied on one side). you mean that even it it's true the the pelvis is in place, if I have a muscular unbalance (and I think it's the case) the pelvis will be forced to its initial position again by the muscles ?